# Flutter Web - Scrollbar with ListView - _positions.isNotEmpty "ScrollController not attached to any scroll views

Tags: flutter, flutter-listview, flutter-scrollbar

This is my Tree:
[image]

This is the code for the build function:

```
    return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
  body: Scrollbar(
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    controller: controller,
    child: ListView(
      controller: controller,
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(
          color: model.cardThemeColor,
          height: 600,
        )
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

code from MyApp:

```
    @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        return Future.value(false);
      },
      child: Navigator(
        key: navigatorKey,
        observers: [
          FirebaseAnalyticsObserver(analytics: analytics),
        ],
        pages: [
          MaterialPage(child: getFirstScreen()),
        ],
        onPopPage: (route, result) {
          if (!route.didPop(result)) return false;
          show404 = false;
          notifyListeners();
          return true;
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

and:

```
  Widget getFirstScreen() {
  return prov.Provider<CalendarAppointmentScreenBloc>(
    create: (c) => CalendarAppointmentScreenBloc(),
    child: prov.Consumer<CalendarAppointmentScreenBloc>(
      builder: (__, bloc, _) => CalendarAppointmentScreen(
        bloc: bloc,
        analytics: analytics,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

}

If I remove the 'isAlwaysShown', I don't have the error.
The error appears after the build function completes. I don't explicitly call the controller's functions.

Comment: Hi There. You gotta post more code. As of now, there is nothing wrong with what you have posted.

Comment: @NisanthReddy Thanks, I added more code.

Comment: It is still not sufficient. Add full code for the Widget which has the `Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,`

Comment: @NisanthReddy This is the full code. I removed the child from the container and still get the error. This is Flutter Web, if it makes a difference.